# uialertcontroller with uipickerview in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

i want to show `UIPickerView` in `UIAlertController`. i do it successfully but display of alert view  is wrong. below is alert view code.

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Select Launguage", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
alertView.modalInPopover = true;
alertView.view.addSubview(pickerView)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
alertView.addAction(action)
presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

picker view code is below;

```
var pickerView = UIPickerView();
self.pickerView.delegate = self
self.pickerView.dataSource = self
```

[image]

"OK" button, title of alert and picker view is overlapped. now please help me how to do it.

Comment: The "Sheet" type is not made to embed a picker, if you want to achieve something similar is better that you create your custom UIViewController with its UIPresentationController. Pay attention that any hack can easily break in future iOS updates. Another solution can be implement a custom keyboard (alias inputView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert new lines via the `message` parameter to create more vertical space.

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Select Language", message: "\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
```

For a better control of the picker view position create the `UIPickerView` instance with `UIPickerView(frame:)` and you have to add the picker view to the subviews of the alert controller.